# Difference between Enthalpy and Heat transferred in a reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, heat

We know at const pressure change in enthalpy is change in internal energy plus work done.
Here by taking enthalpy as heat i can easily think the situation in mind that heat absorbed is due to the two factors
But when enthalpy and heat is used simultaneously i get confused.
I want the logical answer i know the mathematical equations.
I want to think it the way it practically occurs.

Comment: What is your precise definition of the standard enthalpy change for a reaction?

Comment: @ChesterMiller  net heat absorbed or released after a chemical reaction takes place..

Comment: Not during the time the reaction is taking place?  And, what if the final temperature is not equal to the initial temperature?  Does that change the heat of reaction?  And, what if the pressure changes?  How does that affect the heat of reaction?

Comment: @ChesterMiller i dnt know all these answers dats y i amasking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For gases, the heat of reaction at a specified temperature is defined as the amount of heat that has to be added to the system to bring about the change from an initial state of pure reactants in stoichiometric proportions at the specified temperature and 1 bar pressure to the pure products at the same temperature and 1 bar pressure.  This is equal to the standard change in enthalpy of the reaction at the specified temperature. The process for bringing about this change may involve doing work on the surroundings equal to the volume change for products minus reactants times the applied pressure of 1 bar.

Comment: Then what is the diff btwn enthalpy and heat

Comment: For this particular change between initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states, the change in enthalpy is equal to the heat added.  More generally, heat is energy in transit, while enthalpy is a physical property defined by the thermodynamic equilibrium state of a system.

Comment: I got it but when enthalpy not equals to heat can u give me a case ...

Comment: and then if both were not equal at any case the differeence of those 2 parameters heat and enthalpy where that energy goes

Comment: Examples of when change in enthalpy is not equal to heat:  isothermal expansion of an ideal gas; adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas.  In isothermal expansion, the heat goes to work.  In adiabatic expansion, the internal energy change is the result of work, and, since the temperature changes, the enthalpy change is not zero (even though the heat is zero).

Answer (score 2):

Enthalpy and heat are entirely different things.

Enthalpy is a function of state. If you know the state of a system, you know its enthalpy. If you know the starting and ending states of a process, you can find the enthalpy change.

Heat, on the other hand, is an inexact differential. Knowing the initial and final states of a process is not enough information to tell you the heat transfer. Instead, the heat transfer depends on the particular path taken between the states.

For a simple example of why this is important, consider a heat engine. The process is a cycle, meaning the initial and final states are the same, so a cycle of a heat engine has zero enthalpy change. However, the entire point is that the heat engine converts heat into work, so the heat exchange during a cycle is not zero.

That is why the heat exchanged is equal to the enthalpy change only under constant pressure. We need to give extra information (such as that the pressure is constant) to know the path taken during the process in order to say anything meaningful about heat exchange.